# How can I fix polyfill error in react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have this error in react project when I had imported WS module.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

How can I fix this issue.